# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python

I have looked into this before asking my question, but haven't been able to find anything that fits in with my situation.

I'm writing a Python program - a text editor; using Python and Gtk+3.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 58, in on_s_pressed
    if (self.set_title == (filename + " - DeSedit")):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

And here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class DeSedit(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="DeSedit")

    self.set_default_size(650, 500)

    # keyboard shortcuts
    """ <Control>O """
    accel = Gtk.AccelGroup()
    accel.connect(Gdk.keyval_from_name('O'), Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK, 0, self.on_o_pressed)
    self.add_accel_group(accel)
    """ <Control>S """
    accel1 = Gtk.AccelGroup()
    accel1.connect(Gdk.keyval_from_name('S'), Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK, 0, self.on_s_pressed)
    self.add_accel_group(accel1)

    # grid to organize widgets
    self.box = Gtk.Box()
    self.add(self.box)
    # text view
    self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
    self.textview.set_wrap_mode(True)
    self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
    # scroll bar
    scrollwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scrollwindow.add(self.textview)
    self.box.pack_start(scrollwindow, True, True, 0)

# open file dialog
def on_o_pressed(self, *args):
    openDialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Select file to be opened", self,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
        Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
    response = openDialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = openDialog.get_filename()
        with open(filename, 'r') as fRead:
            data = fRead.read()
            self.textbuffer.set_text(data)
            self.set_title(filename + " - DeSedit")
            fRead.close()
        openDialog.destroy()
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        openDialog.destroy()

# save file dialog
def on_s_pressed(self, *args):
    saveDialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Select folder to save file", self,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.SAVE,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
        Gtk.STOCK_SAVE, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
    filename = saveDialog.get_filename()
    if self.set_title == (filename + " - DeSedit"):
        print("hmm")
    response = saveDialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:

        with open(filename, 'w') as fWrite:
            data = self.textbuffer.get_text(self.textbuffer.get_start_iter(),
                                            self.textbuffer.get_end_iter(), True)
            fWrite.write(data)
            fWrite.close()
        saveDialog.destroy()
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        saveDialog.destroy()



window = DeSedit()  # create DeSedit object
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: It would appear that `saveDialog.get_filename()` is returning None.

Comment: This one does not provide a [mcve] (ref: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306049/3001761)

Answer (score 2):

It basically tells you `filename` is a NoneType object, which means `saveDialog.get_filename()` returnded `None`.

According to [the doc](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkfilechooser.html#method-gtkfilechooser--get-filename) this means no file was selected

> gtk.FileChooser.get_filename
>
> def get_filename()
>
> Returns :
>     The currently selected filename, or None if no file is >selected, or the selected file can't be represented with a local filename.

Answer (score 1):

Your filename came from here:

```
filename = saveDialog.get_filename()
```

The function returned `None` for some reason (probably because the user canceled the dialog box - when you cancel a Tkinter file dialog, you get an empty string), then tried to combine that with a string, which cannot be done. Put in some error-handling code to deal with situations where no filename was chosen, like `if not filename: return` or something.